# Installing MeteorJS in Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I currently manage Web App on a LAMP stack hosted with GreenGeeks. As it has scaled up, I have started learning MeteorJS on my local machine and am thinking about redeveloping the app in Meteor to support more concurrent connections. My questions are:

- Can Meteor simply be hosted in a Simple Amazon S3 Bucket with no need for a stack of any kind? Is this smart? When something seems this simple, I get nervous.
- Is Meteor as portable as it feels? Migrating a LAMP app from one server to another can be a real pain. This "feels" like it's as simple as zipping up the whole thing and simply dragging it anywhere. Again, *feels too simple = nervous.*
- Is meteor the right choice if I am looking to maximize concurrent connections and reduce the number of times I need to go to the server for information? My app loads about 2 MB of data per user and I'd love a situation where this can be loaded once and the user has it available to interact with without going to the server (unless it changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answers to your questions:

- Well actually You can deploy your meteor app into an Amazon EC2 instance, the process is pretty easy, take a look to [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11K_DSrhJzQ)
- Meteor is incredible portable, actually it was made with nodejs, therefore it inherits its features
- You are in the right way, you know meteor is reactive, it acts in real time, also uses mongoDB, which is incredible faster than a regular SQL database, so in general meteor's performance is amazing, in fact, there are lots of packages that improve even more the performance of your app [like this one](https://github.com/meteorhacks/unblock/) and many others